# How to set self view height using constraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

So I have been moving parts of the code to use constraints rather than the older way of doing things using frames. This is the current code that I need to move. I need to change the height of the view when I hide\unhide the tabbar below when the user presses a button.

```
CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
newFrame.size.height += 44
self.view.frame = newFrame;
```

self.view is the UIViewController. I want to set the height of the view shown in the picture. There is no way to add a height constraint to it (you can set it on the subviews though easily which i dont want)[image: Selected View whose height needs to be set using constraints]

I don't see a way of setting the self view height using constraints.

thanks
arpit

Answer (score 1):

This short [tutorial](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/) will be helpful for you.

You can do it using VFL (I personally prefer, see link above) or by this kind of code:

```
[yourView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourView    
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     relatedBy:0 
                                                        toItem:nil
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
                                                    multiplier:1 
                                                      constant:requiredHeight]];
```

This piece of code will add a constraint on height for `yourView` specified by `requiredHeight`. Before start coding please take a look at intrinsicContentSize and updateConstraints methods.

When setting constraints please remember to firstly set (for a view you will set constraints) `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` flag to NO (it is set to YES by default). Also reading [this](https://medium.com/@NSomar/auto-layout-best-practices-for-minimum-pain-c130b2b1a0f6) should put some light on the topic.